# Orpheus for Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I am a user of Orpheus. There is nothing better for table handlin,f.ex.
I have downloaded your version for D2009. How do you get it work for You with
all the CHARs in there, and without using H- for the strings ?

Comment: Hm.. Nothing better for table handling...? We left orpheus for devexpress a couple of years ago, and never looked back.

Answer (score 2):

I think the project is maintained at sourceforge [TurboPower Orpheus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tporpheus/). The version called 4.07 Unicode likely supports Delphi 2009. There's also another build on May 22, 2009 by [SongBeamer](http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/). [Thread: Disabling Unicode in D2009?](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=17311) mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, Nick Hodges is now the admin of the sourceforge project. It should be updated soon to support 2009/2010.